# Изменение интерфейса из второго класса

Tags: java, android

Есть класс `MainActivity` из которого запускаю другой класс, через `startintent`, допустим, `TwoActivity`. Но `TwoActivity` не видит интерфейс, то есть `findViewById` не видит `ID` элементов на интерфейсе.

Может быть есть проще решение.

Суть такова: есть два класса. отдельным файлом, нужно чтобы при вызове метода во втором классе, менялся интерфейс экрана. Подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Вы хотите из одной активити получить доступ к разметке другой активити? Если да, то это невозможно. Единовременно может существовать/быть активной только одна активити

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Тобишь чтобы изиенять интерфейс  я должен это делать в одной активити. Я вас понял Спасибо!

Comment: Если стартовать другую активити, то можно положить в Bundle интента информацию о том какие изменения и с чем произойдут.